# Does --hosts not override env.hosts defined within the fabfile itself?

Tags: python, fabric

If I have: `env.hosts = ['my.host.a', 'my.host.b', 'my.host.c']`, does calling the script with `fab -H my.host.a` not override what's defined in the fabfile?

I set `env.hosts` as a global at the top of my fabfile. When I pass in `-H`, my tasks are still executed on the full list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/usage/execution.html) says that the assignment in the fabfile takes precedence.

> `$ fab -H host1,host2 mytask`
>
> Such an invocation is directly equivalent to `env.hosts = ['host1', 'host2']`
>
> [...]
>
> It is important to know that these command-line switches are interpreted **before** your fabfile is loaded: any reassignment to `env.hosts` or `env.roles` in your fabfile will overwrite them.